# How to use Excel built-in format(accounting format) on dataframe of Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to output my dataframe in pandas to excel.

```
data = {'Names':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], Attending Cost’: [1, 1, 1, 1], 'Summary':[2, 2, 2, 2]}
data_2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test", engine='xlsxwriter')                
data_2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', 
startrow=5)
writer.save()
```

I am hoping that I can use Excel's built-in accounting format on the last two columns, but I have no idea how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track, you just need to add excel's accountancy format to your workbook. So continuing with your current code:

```
data = {'Names':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], Attending Cost’: [1, 1, 1, 1], 'Summary':[2, 2, 2, 2]}
data_2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test", engine='xlsxwriter')                
data_2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', 
startrow=5)

# get the clsx writer workbook and worksheet objects
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Add your accountancy format
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 44})

# Set format without assigning column width for columns C and D
worksheet.set_column('C:C', None, format1)
worksheet.set_column('D:D', None, format1)

# Close the pandas Excel Writer and output Excel File
writer.save()
```

A full list of the formats can be found [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html?highlight=set_num_format#set_num_format).